# How to find the photon view id?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm developing my first multiplayer game using photon and I should find the user's photon view id via script how can I do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at least check the documentation or else you will be popping questions here every 3 min. Here you go:

https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_view.html